# Angular interfering with jQuery find

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Good Day,

I have some javascript code where I'm attempting to use jQuery find() method to apply some style to a div element that contains a class called gridfooter once the page renders.

Here's the pre-rendered HTML of the grid footer:

```
<div ng-if="messages != null && messages.length > 0" class="gridfooter">
    <table class="list-footer">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="gridController" id="message-grid" ng-show="visible" class="ng-scope">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="gridheader" style="color: red; border: 1px solid red;">..</div>
    <div class="gridcontent" style="color: red; border: 1px solid red;">..</div>
    <div class="gridfooter">..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript that I'm using to find the gridfooter:

```
var thePanel = $('#message-grid .panel'),
    theFooter = thePanel.find(".gridfooter"),
    theContent = thePanel.find(".gridcontent"),
    theContentFooter = theContent.find(".gridfooter");

    $('#message-grid .panel').children().css({ "color" : "red", "border": "1px solid red" });
```

My problem is the div with the gridfooter class isn't styled like gridheader/gridcontent.

However, when I remove the angular ng-if directive from the pre-rendered HTML:

```
<div class="gridfooter">
    <table class="list-footer">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Then the rendered div with gridfooter is styled

```
<div ng-controller="gridController" id="message-grid" ng-show="visible" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="gridheader" style="color: red; border: 1px solid red;">..</div>
        <div class="gridcontent" style="color: red; border: 1px solid red;">..</div>
        <div class="gridfooter" style="color: red; border: 1px solid red;">..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the reason why this is not working is because:  [jQuery not working with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482047/jquery-not-working-with-ng-repeat-results).  The answer to this question deals with event delegation.

Would I be correctly assuming that the ng-if handlers is bound at runtime, therefore .gridfooter doesn't exist?

If so, I'm not 100% sure how to fix this.

Any suggestions?

TIA,

coson

Comment: why dont you write css? `$('#message-grid .panel').children().css({...});` is equal to `#message-grid .panel > * { ... }` in css

Comment: also, you are right that the jquery code executes once at runtime and must be re-called everytime the angular output changes the markup (i guess), but event delegation is event-based, so you'd have to run that code on angular callbacks (dont know if those exist)

Comment: @Alex - The children().css({ }) was just to see if I could apply a style.  I planned on removing it once I solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ng-class` to apply styles to your elements. It's not a good pratice to use JQuery side by side Angular JS code, besides in directives.

[ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an
>   HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes
>   to be added.

You can evaluate any expression and then apply the class to your element.