# jquery click event is not working with angular.js ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a nested (tertiary) menu list with a jquery click event on the back. jQuery click does not fire when the menu item is clicked. The jQuery event works well if the values inside the HTML are static.

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul class="collapsible-list" ng-controller="ViewCtrl">
    <li class="collapsible-list-subnav" ng-repeat="view in views">
        <a class="collapsible-list-parent">{{view.name}}</a>
        <ul class="collapsible-list secondary">
            <li class="collapsible-list-subnav">
                <a class="collapsible-list-parent">Public Views</a>
                <ul class="collapsible-list tertiary">
                    <li ng-repeat="publicview in view.publicviews">
                        <a>{{publicview.title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="collapsible-list-subnav">
                <a class="collapsible-list-parent">Private Views</a>
                <ul class="collapsible-list tertiary">
                    <li ng-repeat="privateview in view.privateviews">
                        <a>{{privateview.title}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
define([ 'angular', 'controllers-module'], function(angular,
    controllers) {

    controllers.controller("ViewCtrl", [
        "$scope",
        "$rootScope",
        "directiveBinder",
        '$timeout',
        '$stateParams',
        '$resource',
        '$state',
        function($scope, $rootScope,directiveBinder, $timeout, $stateParams, $resource, $state) {

            $scope.engines = [ {
            name : 'name1',
            publicviews : [ {
                title : 'First public View'
            } ],
            privateviews : [ {
                title : 'First private View'
            } ]
        }, {
            name : 'name2',
            publicviews : [ {
                title : 'Second public View'
            } ],
            privateviews : [ {
                title : 'Second private View'
            } ]
        } ];

        $('.collapsible-list-parent').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().addClass('open');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: what jquery version are you using? have you tried to use `$(document).on('click', ...`? why are you using jquery and not ng-click?

Comment: I would suggest you to use [Collapse (ui.bootstrap.collapse)](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse), do it angularjs way.

Comment: Poosible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482047/jquery-not-working-with-ng-repeat-results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the elements are added dynamically by ng-repeat the .click event is not binded to them. Try to use [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$( "ul" ).delegate( ".collapsible-list-parent", "click", function() {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: First: you link is broken, second: `delegate` is superseded by [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Solved the link issue, due to the fact that i have no idea what jQuery version he is running, it seemed like the best solution.

Comment: @CristiMarian Thanks for the solution. My jQuery is v1.10.2. I've got an issue with the jQuery collapse animation though. After the click happens the menu collapses but after a second it uncollapses immediately. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you send me link to a fiddle where you can reproduce it?  I'll try to see what's causing it.

Answer (score 3):

When we use ng-repeat and need to trigger a jquery click event just try this it worked for me.

```
$(document).on("click", ".className", function() {

//your code here...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using jQuery code in an angularjs controller is the right way to do this, a sample to do the same without the animation will be like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {

})

app.controller('ViewCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.views = [{
    name: 'name1',
    publicviews: [{
      title: 'First public View'
    }],
    privateviews: [{
      title: 'First private View'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'name2',
    publicviews: [{
      title: 'Second public View'
    }],
    privateviews: [{
      title: 'Second private View'
    }]
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <ul class="collapsible-list" ng-controller="ViewCtrl">
    <li class="collapsible-list-subnav" ng-repeat="view in views">
      <a class="collapsible-list-parent" ng-click="open = !open">{{view.name}}</a>
      <ul class="collapsible-list secondary" ng-show="open">
        <li class="collapsible-list-subnav">
          <a class="collapsible-list-parent" ng-click="popen = !popen">Public Views</a>
          <ul class="collapsible-list tertiary" ng-show="popen">
            <li ng-repeat="publicview in view.publicviews">
              <a>{{publicview.title}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="collapsible-list-subnav">
          <a class="collapsible-list-parent" ng-click="ropen = !ropen">Private Views</a>
          <ul class="collapsible-list tertiary" ng-show="ropen">
            <li ng-repeat="privateview in view.privateviews">
              <a>{{privateview.title}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

If you want to use animations you can make use of [angularjs animation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) which uses css3 animations.

Comment: I cannot run the code snippet unfortunately, because of the company restrictions.