# Angular/JQuery can focus on input but can't click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, click, focus

I can call the focus() method on an input element on my page and it will bring it into view however I can't appear to actually click into the field?

The input is as follows

```
<input alt="ACCEPT_TEXT"
       title="ACCEPT_TEXT"
       placeholder="I Understand"
       ng-model="leafNode.transMap[translationLanguage].translation"
       id="leafNode_82"
       class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">
```

```
$($('input[alt^="ACCEPT_TEXT"]')[0]).focus(); // works

$($('input[alt^="ACCEPT_TEXT"]')[0]).click(); // has no effect
```

When clicked with the mouse the cursor goes into the input and it goes yellow but right now it just focus and doesn't insert the cursor.

[image: Desired Result]

This has me a little blocked at the minute so any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mark.

Comment: Are these inputs for text? If so you're missing type="text" in your <input>s

Comment: thanks Vtange I introduced the text and yet to no avail. Focuses but no click

Comment: any reason you're not using ng-focus and ng-click? It might be a problem between Jquery and Angular -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958004/jquery-click-event-is-not-working-with-angular-js-ng-repeat

Comment: As I understand it, ng-focus and ng-click are used to bind the reaction after the element has been focussed upon or clicked on. I need to simulate the actual click itself to place the cursor into the input.