# JQUERY function doesn't work anymore after adding elements via ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is my html layout [image]

This is my jquery code [image]

This is a chat style layout, when I click the chatbox header the chatbox will be pushed to the bottom.[image][image]

It works actually, but only if the layout is preloaded not dynamically added via ng-repeat.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this ? Please help thanks

Comment: Please add code to your question. Not images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery not working with ng-repeat results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482047/jquery-not-working-with-ng-repeat-results)

Comment: Please, stop using jquery with angularJS (unless you encapsulate this in a directive or something else). This is one of the worst mistakes.

Comment: Why is that ? O_O ?

Comment: How do I do that ? I'm pretty new to angularjs you see =_=;

Comment: use "ng-click" on your header, do not use jquery selector when you use angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
$(document).on("click", ".chatbox-header", function(e){..
```

Comment: Yep, saw it on a previous post twas much easier than creating a directive lol

Comment: @RichCuer Though it is easier, as a good practice one should limit using Jquery as much as possible while using AngularJs :)

Comment: Yes sir ! understood :3