# Bootstrap accordion does not expand on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

In the accounts index, I would like to display the account information which im doing in a table, and in an accordion or dropwon my purchases information.

My **Account Model** is

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
#Associations
has_many :purchases, dependent: :destroy  do
  def total
      total = 0
      self.each { |purchase| total += purchase.total }
      total
  end
end

has_many :sales, dependent: :destroy

has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy

#Validations
validates :name, presence: true
validates :category, presence: true
```

end

Which shows in its **index.html.erb**

```
<div class="row table-responsive" style="margin-top:50px;">
<table id="accountstable"class="table table-striped custab tablesorter">
  <thead>
  <tr style="margin-bottom:20px;">
    <%= link_to 'Add Account', new_account_path ,:class => "btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-center"%>
  </tr>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Category</th>
     <th>Balance</th>
     <th>Transactions</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <% @accounts.each do |account| %>

 <tr>
  <td><%= account.name %></td>
  <td><%= account.category %></td>
  <td><%= 0 +  account.purchases.total %></td>

  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_account_path(account), :class=>"btn btn-info btn-xs" %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Delete', account, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sure ?' },:class=>"btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

I would like to expand on row click account.purchases, but im not getting it right.

Comment: Would this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389775/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-js-on-table-cells-almost-done

Comment: Actually no, my hidden content is not hiding! Using static content works perfectly but when i                                         <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="<%= account.id %>">
           <% account.purchases.each do  |purchase| %> 
          <tr>
            <td><%= purchase.date %></td>
          </tr>
         <% end %>
         </div>

Comment: I'm sorry.  Can you describe what is going wrong in more detail?