# Bootstrap collapsing whole table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I know there is a way to collapse table rows in bootstrap, e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389775/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-js-on-table-cells-almost-done). But is it possible for me to have a button/link/etc. that I can click, which collapses the whole table instead of just table rows?

I am currently building tables based on database information and these tables can get pretty big. If i have 4-5 tables I'd like for the user to be aple to collapse/expand these tables as he/she chooses.

Is this possible somehow? I can not seem to find any answers when I google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to place your tables inside of a `panel` (using Bootstrap 3.2 - for example), you can then collapse the `panel-body` element without using javascript. Here is an example:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary accordion"> <!-- Panel (collapasable) -->

    <div class="panel-heading"> <!-- Panel head -->
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=".accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            Collapse Me On Click!
        </a>           
    </div> <!-- END Panel head -->

    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"> <!-- Collapsable section -->

        <div class="panel-body"> <!-- Panel body -->

            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Col1</th>
                        <th>Col2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div> <!-- END Panel body -->

    </div> <!-- END Collapse section -->

</div>
```

CSS (not really needed):

```
a {
    color: white;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
   border: solid 1px; 
}
```

And a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3m6b10h/4/)

Comment: This is really nice, and I'm actually having my tables in a panel. I'll check this out.

Answer (score 2):

I can provide Two solutions to this, JQuery and Bootstrap.

If you are open to a JQuery solution have a look at this.

---

### JQUERY SOLUTION

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapsable">
   <table>
      <tr><td> word </td><td> another word </td></tr>
      <tr><td> word </td><td> another word </td></tr>
    </table>
</div><br />
<button> Click me </button>
```

**CSS**

```
table, th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$("button").on("click", function()
{
    $(".collapsable").slideToggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3m6b10h/) Using a button you can slide the table up and down to hide/show.

If you are using Bootstrap 3.0 then how about this example?

---

## BOOTSTRAP SOLUTION

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
      <table>
          <tr><td> word </td><td> another word </td></tr>
          <tr><td> word </td><td> another word </td></tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

Same as above.

[Boostrap collapse Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgfeyjrm/)

Comment: Now that I think about it I cant see you achieving this without Javascript, maybe HTML5 has an element that can achieve it but in all honesty as much as browsers are working hard to accomodate HTML5 its still not widely accepted by the range of browsers available and most certainly in use today.

Answer (score 0):

pherhaps something like this? using bootstraps accordian: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/30/

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Table 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Bob</td>
                    <td>is cool</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Jane</td>
                    <td>is cool</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can add css to make the panel of the collapsible the table itself:

```
.panel-body {
    padding:0px;
}
.table {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```