# Correctly create bootstrap accordion in html table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, accordion

I found several questions similar to what I was trying to accomplish and actually took one of the examples and tried to adapt to do what I want to achieve to no avail.

I want to be able to create a bootstrap accordion inside of a regular html table but I just can't seem to get it right. If I click on the first cell, it expands the accordion's div, but then when I click on the second cell, that cell too shows. How can I make it properly obey the accordion style in that clicking a single cell will only collapse/expand a single section at a time.

I'm okay with multiple rows being expanded, and I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing or doing wrong. I have been at this for a few hours and the answer is still eluding me. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<body>
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Credit</th>
            <th>Debit</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id ="accordion" class="accordion-group">
        <tr>
            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion">1</td>
             <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo22" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion">05 May 2013</td>
            <td>Credit Account</td>
            <td class="text-success">$150.00</td>
            <td class="text-error"></td>
            <td class="text-success">$150.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                <div class=" accordian-body collapse" id="demo1"> Demo1 </div>
                <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo22"> Demo22 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>05 May 2013</td>
            <td>Credit Account</td>
            <td class="text-success">$11.00</td>
            <td class="text-error"></td>
            <td class="text-success">$161.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo2" class="accordian-body collapse">Demo2</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" class="accordion-toggle">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>05 May 2013</td>
            <td>Credit Account</td>
            <td class="text-success">$500.00</td>
            <td class="text-error"></td>
            <td class="text-success">$661.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"  class="hiddenRow"><div id="demo3" class="accordian-body collapse">Demo3</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Dj7Y/2082/

I'm able to create a similar table structure using all divs and bootstrap columns which is not hard, but I want a pure html table structure. I was going to try to use this in an angular directive and combine it with other code I have that runs on tables.

Comment: This is the original question I used as a base: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389775/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-js-on-table-cells-almost-done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this helps: I believe this is what you're trying to do and if so it's just your data targets are off slightly.

```js
$('.accordian-body').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).closest("table")
        .find(".collapse.in")
        .not(this)
        .collapse('toggle')
})
```

```css
tbody tr.info td:hover {
  background-color: #266080;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
  -moz-transition-duration: 500ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3>Collapsing Tables</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>EMail</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>ID #</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="info">
            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table1" class="accordion-toggle">One</td>
            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table2" class="accordion-toggle">Two</td>
            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table3" class="accordion-toggle">Three</td>
            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table4" class="accordion-toggle">Four</td>
            <td data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#table5" class="accordion-toggle">Five</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="accordian-body collapse" id="table1">
                    <td><a href="#">Link</a>

                    </td>
                    <td>Sub-A</td>
                    <td>Sub-B</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="accordian-body collapse" id="table2">
                    <th>One-A</th>
                    <th>Two-A</th>
                    <th>Three-A</th>
                    <th>Four-A</th>
                    <th>Five-A</th>
                    <th>Six-A</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="accordian-body collapse" id="table3">
                    <td>One-B</td>
                    <td>Two-B</td>
                    <td>Three-B</td>
                    <td>Four-B</td>
                    <td>Five-B</td>
                    <td>Six-B</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="accordian-body collapse" id="table4">
                    <td>One-C</td>
                    <td>Two-C</td>
                    <td>Three-C</td>
                    <td>Four-C</td>
                    <td>Five-C</td>
                    <td>Six-C</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="accordian-body collapse" id="table5">
                    <td>One-D</td>
                    <td>Two-D</td>
                    <td>Three-D</td>
                    <td>Four-D</td>
                    <td>Five-D</td>
                    <td>Six-D</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This table is really neat, but it doesn't seem to be displaying the correct accordion behavior as I understand it. When I expand any heading, shouldn't the last one collapse on its own? I am able to expand all sections and collapse them individually, but I thought it should only allow a single section to show at any one time.

Comment: Revised with some JS.

Comment: You're pretty handy with the JS. The solution  you posted works, but naturally the next follow up question is do you know if this can be achieved with pure html tags? Either way, this does pretty much what I wanted and can be tweaked to fit my data set. Thanks!

Comment: No, not possible without js. Sorry.