# Bootstrap/HTML - multiple level table with folding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement multiple level table with folding like this one

*Top by usage, Top by delay, Top by memory rows can be folded*
[image: example]

Currently i am working with bootstrap. I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389775/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-js-on-table-cells-almost-done) except that i need to see columns only in expanded part and so far i was not able to twist its functionality. It does not have to be implemented with bootstrap.

Thank you for your suggestions.

//EDIT: Forgot to mention, another problem is that table needs to support scrolling within the table without moving page.

Comment: hey can you put some code .?

Comment: the image has been taken from custom Eclipse plug-in and cannot be embedded into HTML. I am trying to rework this plug-in design into HTML. I am looking for smart way to do this without putting in much effort into frontend css development (I am not a frond end dev :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are always tricky. =(
So in order to make the table scroll without moving the whole page:

```
table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Just set a reasonable height and width for the table and then it is possible to scroll it up and down. Yet, this comes with a few caveats. First some mobile browsers are still having issues with `overflow: scroll` and secondly you will have to actively tap/click on the table once before you can scroll it.

All of that being said you sure would have to throw some JavaScript or a whole lot of CSS on the table in order to make the toggle work.