# How to make drill down tables in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to make  each value in one of the column of table as clickable so that I can develop drill down functionality using Zeppelin Table.  But following sample code is not working at all.

```
print(s"""%table
a\tb\n%html <button>x</button>1\t2\n%html <button>y</button>3\t4
""")
```

Comment: I am using Zeppelin 0.6.1

Comment: Could you share screenshots including the paragraph and interpreter bindings?

Comment: I am using Apache Spark and there are no other bindings except Angular. My actual code is quite complex, I have created this code for easy testing. You can just copy paste this code. If, you remove %html, it will work but then button comes as a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take quite some effort to make this work.

The basic idea is converting a data source (e.g. Spark DataFrame) to a complete and self contained HTML section and which is interpreted by [Zeppelin](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/displaysystem/basicdisplaysystem.html#html). Hide and show need to be handled by javascript library.

Zeppelin using Bootstrap, so we shall use bootstrap library directly. This SO might help [Bootstrap cllapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389775/twitter-bootstrap-use-collapse-js-on-table-cells-almost-done). Perhaps need more styling.

If you are just wanna drilldown function while not strictly with table. And if you are using Spark, it might be a bit easy with [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/blob/master/docs/DemoDrillDown.md) to implement the feature like [Highcharts column drill down](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown)

Comment: Thanks Rockie, I am exploring spark-highcharts since morning but unfortunately, I need the functionality with table data.

Comment: The closest highcharts is heat map http://www.highcharts.com/demo/heatmap

Comment: Hi Rockie, I just need click on the table row and display another table in the following  paragraph based on the data in first column of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the heatmap link. I need this for another use case :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally my code worked. The issue seems to be if you have html tag in the first column, it will not work. However, it works in all the other columns. Just add one more cols in the front and it worked.

```
print(s"""%table
 dummy\ta\tb\np1\t%html <button>x</button>1\t2\np1\t%html <button>y</button>3\t4
""")
```

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Zeppelin 0.7.0, one can use html even in the first column.