# only closing specific collapsible items when opening one in Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some trubble with my Bootstrap collapsible items. According to the answer [Answer with the corresponding javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26594300) I want to only close the collapsible items from my table, because I have other collapsible items on my page (in the menu). That items are working that you can open and and it won't close them automatically (I want it to work like that). Now I insert that javascript code from that Answer (link above), when I open one collapseable item it will close all other collapsibles on the site. How to only close specific ones?

Basically I want this: [JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLfMU/1283/)`klick the link fot the code`. If you click on the first table on one row it should open the text and if you click on another row on the SAME table it should close the other one. When clicking on the second table on a row it should not close the opened content of the first table.

Thank you for all the answers :D

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: @ZimSystem I added the symple code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
        alert('The collapsible content is about to be hidden.');
    });
    $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
        alert('The collapsible content is now hidden.');
    });
});
</script>
```